# LinkedBlockingQueue alternatives for JDK 6

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am using [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) for my threadPool

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 
                       21, 
                       10,
                       TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                       new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>())
```

and i suffer from the memory leak [Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6805775) (the memory is full of LinkedBlockingQueue Nodes , slowing down gradually), which is fixed in JDK 7.

I dont want to change the run time environment or my JDK for now.

LinkedBlockingQueue has no size limit , unlike the other implementations of BlockingQueue Interface. Can you suggest any alternative queue ?

Comment: Do you want the producer to throw an exception if the consumer is too slow?  If you have tasks living so long they become tenured you have a serious issue anyway. IMHO you just ensure the consumer is always faster than the producer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i have no speed balance issue , its just the memory leak of linkedblockingqueue piling up , as this is a daemon process

Comment: As the bug appears to be fixed in the version you are using, I would look for other explainations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i believe so. I think i will try to use a fixed size implementation eventually

Comment: You can also use the `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` in the event that the consumer is slow (even temporarily)  This can allow you to set the size pretty small. Given you have 20 threads, the queue should be empty most of the time.  You can try `SynchronousQueue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix bug-id you link to has also been backported to Java 6. It has been fixed in Java 6 since Java 6 Update 19, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2186685 (this one is BTW linked on the bug you refer to).

Comment: Thank you.  I guess i learn one more point on how to read the Bug Details. Affected versions list would help me '6u11,6u22,7'. Is there a way to just apply this bug fix to my Runtime Environment? my system says 'java version "1.6.0_32"'

Comment: @kommradHomer I believe the listing of 6u22 in the affected versions is incorrect; what is the actual JRE version you are using?

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05)

Comment: It is listed as fixed in the [releasenotes of Java 6 Update 19 as well](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u19-141078.html)

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayBlockingQueue` which is backed by a fixed-sized array.

`PriorityBlockingQueue` - it is an unbounded blocking, here the elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time.

Comment: +1 You can also use LinkedBlockingQueue with a fixed capacity.